# XML with too many Elements

Tags: java, android, xml, exception

i'm currently using the simple framework to map a xml response to an Object.
This object has an Attribute of an ArrayList of another Class. The code is running on android.

The problem in my case is, that the framework ends with an exception after the 63rd Element.

```
XMLPULLPARSEREXCEPTION: UNTERMINATED ENTITY REF
```

Example of the xml response:

```
<assignedUsers>
<user name="1" titel="user1" groupname="group1" ...><user name="2" titel="user2"... >...<user name="n" titel="userN" ...>
</assignedUsers>
```

The response contains arround 100 users. The file contains 23599 characters. I checked the response and it is fine. If i shorten the list to 63 elements, my code ends without any problems. Any suggestions how to handle this?

Thx for your help

Update - here is the stacktrace:

```
   org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref (position:START_TAG <dashboard name='ABC 2012 Character Comparison (Cluster Top 5)'>@12:14965 in java.io.InputStreamReader@a9404f80)
        at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readEntity(KXmlParser.java:1203)
        at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readValue(KXmlParser.java:1385)
        at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.parseStartTag(KXmlParser.java:1109)
        at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:369)
        at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.PullReader.read(PullReader.java:105)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.PullReader.next(PullReader.java:89)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.NodeReader.readElement(NodeReader.java:111)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.stream.InputElement.getNext(InputElement.java:216)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeList.populate(CompositeList.java:169)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeList.read(CompositeList.java:120)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readVariable(Composite.java:623)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:573)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readUnion(Composite.java:549)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.java:532)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:445)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Builder.read(Composite.java:1383)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:201)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:148)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:625)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:606)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:584)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:543)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:521)
        at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:426)
```

Here is the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response>
<loggedIn>true</loggedIn>
<errorMessage></errorMessage>
<firstName>Homer Jay</firstName>
<lastName>Simpson</lastName>
<email>abc@def.com</email>
<userId></userId>
<assignedDashboards>
<dashboard name="ABC 2012 Opponent Comparison (Table Top 5)" 
guid="d37e8537-16bc-44db-af13-5e12bca509a2" groupName="Global ABC"
groupDescription="" groupExpanded="NO" id="62" dashboardGroupId="10" />
<dashboard name="DEF 2012 Character Comparison (Jerry & Tom)"
guid="3624215a-7d27-406f-a9cb-b25663462aa4" groupName="Global ABC" 
groupDescription="" groupExpanded="NO" id="68" dashboardGroupId="10" />
</assignedDashboards>
</response>
```

Here is the class to map:
    @Root(name="response")
    public class ResponseDashboardList {

```
@Element(name="loggedIn")
private String loggedIn;

@Element(name="errorMessage", required = false)
private String errorMessage;

@Element(name="firstName")
private String firstName;

@Element(name="lastName")
private String lastName;

@Element(name="email")
private String email;

@Element(name="userId")
private String userId;

@ElementList (required = false)
private List<Dashboard> assignedDashboards;
```

The command to parse the file:

ResponseDashboardList responseDashboardList = 
    serializer.read(ResponseDashboardList.class, file);

Comment: Need to see the code you are using for parsing and real XML contents - not a modified "example".

Comment: can you post more error logs please? maybe one of the users has some contains specials characters that are not correctly encoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without more details, but look for ampersands in your data in the last (37?) elements.

It's probably them getting through unescaped, which XML parsers will interpret as the start of an entity (see [predefined entities in XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) for more background on entities).

Comment: In the following element was the symbol "&". That was the problem. Thanks a lot!